# SSH server only allows one client session connect via it's public IP address

Tags: 18.04, ssh, openssh, port-forwarding

Alright, here's a weird one that's stumped me for the past couple hours:

My server is running Ubuntu 18.04, ufw is disabled, and I just reinstalled openssh-server. Maybe it's worth noting that it's connected to my router via WiFi, this is just due to me being unable to run an Ethernet cable from the router to the machine.

If I ssh from local ip's (169.168.1.XXX) everything works normal, server doesn't complain, no noticable lag. However, connecting via it's public IP address gets weird.

I believe to have port forwarded properly, my router didn't want me to open 22, so I created a rule on the router: Global ~~2200~~ 2222 , Host: 22. This seems to work fine, as if I run the command 'ssh user@XXX.XXX.X.XXX -p 2222' on another machine, it prompts me to login to the 'user' account, even if I'm away.

However, if I open another terminal, and run the same 'ssh user@XXX.XXX.X.XXX -p 2222', it errors out with a connection timeout.

I've tried to ssh from windows, Ubuntu, my phone and sftp from windows, and get the same results, local ip works fine everytime, the first one to ssh/sftp logs in just fine, but every subsequent errors out with a connection timeout.

Anyone have any ideas on what I might've overlooked?

Comment: There is a `MaxSessions` variable in `sshd_config` which controls this, but it defaults to 10.

Comment: Perhaps it's your router that's being weird?

Comment: What exactly does the router rule do? Does it say "all traffic coming in on port 2222 should be forwarded to host Host on port 22 with source port 2200"? If you enter a fixed source port, then NAT will only work for that session. Perhaps you can leave the source port blank (meaning use whatever port is available)?

Comment: @Jos sorry for the confusion, I mistakenly thought that ~~X~~ would strikethrough X, what the rule does is take global port 2222 and forward it to 22. (I originally posted with the rule being 2200, but that was inconsistent with the latter part of my post). As far as what im allowed to set for a rule, I have a global port range, say 2222-2232 (It defaults to 2222-2222 if I only fill out one side of the range), Host port and protocol.

Comment: In that case, run `tcpdump` on your server and log incoming traffic on port 22 from the router. If the second session doesn't get through at all, it's a router issue (and we won't be able to help you).